# enabling CORS for set of websites

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cors

I am using

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

in my php files to enable CORS for ajax request on cross sites. I have list of websites stored on my database. Now my problem is how could I enable CORS only for the websites stored on my database, and block ajax request from rest of the websites which are not listed in my database. Also I want to know about drawbacks and solution of enabling CORS for all websites for cross site ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you can check for the URL as

```
             $incomingOrigin = $webURL;

   $hotdat = array();
   foreach ($hotelURL as $releted){         //$hotelURL is an array from your database
       $addURL = $releted->url;              // $releted->url the db field name for url
       array_push($hotdat, $addURL);
   }

   if ($incomingOrigin !== null && isOriginAllowed($incomingOrigin, $hotdat)== TRUE)
     {
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $incomingOrigin");
    }else{
    echo ("CSRF protection in POST request: detected invalid Origin header: " . $incomingOrigin);
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://bookingpoints.com");
}
```